# Бак — бачонок, бочка — бочонок

Tags: орфография

Можно ли сказать, что слово *бачонок* — это от слова *бак*, например как в *бачонок машины потёк*, в то время как *бочонок* — это от слова *бочка*, например как в *бочонок нефти*?

Comment: Словарь пропускает только бочонок — небольшая бочка и бачок — небольшой бак. Все ответы — в словарях! Или почти все)

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, слова бак и бочка имеют разную этимологию, и это не корни с чередованием.

Бак - это от back, спина или закрытая-закрывающая часть. Поэтому бак - это просто сосуд для хранения чего-то, воды - бак+лаж+ка(по-клажа - класть-лаж-положенное в бак, в запас)

А бочка - от слова бок, сосуд сделанный по определённой технологии с помощью деформации боковой поверхности, для придания ей прочности. То есть бочка - это способ или технология создание ёмкости для хранения, либо сосуд по этой технологии изготовленный.

Что же касательно суффиксов. Суффикс -онок -ёнок - это суффикс производной от основы. Волк - волчонок, заяц - зайчонок - ребёнок определённого вида животного. Поэтому бок-бочка-бочонок - звучит нормально, бочонок - производная от бок, созданный с помощь боков и маленький, не такой как бочка. А вот бак - бачонок, звучит уже странно, так как бак - это название вида предмета, а не родовое, или указывающее на технологию - то есть качественное слово. Есть слово бочковой, но слово **бАк**овый - это уже морской жаргон, правый по ходу судна, где **бак** - это название определённой части судна, то есть не качественное прилагательное, а относительное.

Насчёт кулачонок - ну как бы Достоевский его употребил, конечно, хотя более употребимое кулачишко, кулачок - они уже маленькие. Кулачонок же звучит как название сына кулака), а не как "маленький кулак". Хотя "кулачонки" во множественно числе, более употребимо и звучит. А "пальчонок" - увы, не нашёл на нацкорпусе и это изобретение современных словарей, которые пишут ножчонками.

Если же говорить, "в машине бачонок потёк" - то, Лео, конечно тебя поймут, но подумают что ты сказал бочонок, а не бАчонок, в устной речи выделить как-то отдельно безударную А не получится. Либо подумают, что ты описался и написал вместо О букву А. Так что лучше говорить "в машинке бачонка потекла" - так будет максимально экстравагантно, и слова бочонка(ед число) нет. А бачонка, даже если это ошибка, но таки есть и кошачья правда на твоей стороне:

> На дворе 3 бачонка квасных средних, да катка перетирка, кочерга, ухват, сковородник железные. Документы следственных дел Ваньки Каина и других московских преступников (1741-1752).

Answer (score 1):

Открываем список всех слов с суффиксом [-онок-](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC_-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA).
Все слова мужского рода в этом списке одушевленные. Из неодушевленных только

```
кулак, кулачок, кулачонок
палец, пальчик, пальчонок
```

Но здесь видно откуда пальцы растут. Эти слова - производные от множественных ручонок, пальчонков и кулачонков.

В итоге не вписывается в теорию

```
бак, бачок, бачонок
```

Тут налицо закономерность по одушевленному/неодушевленному, или  множественному как у пальчонков, кулачонков

Можно еще суффикс [-ёнок-](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC_-%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) глянуть, для подтверждения теории